# What does the notation $\langle a|b|c\rangle$ mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation

What does the notation $\langle a|b|c\rangle$ mean? I saw this in a Quantum Mechanics book and couldn’t understand it

Comment: See [Bra–ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)

Comment: Is the operator $b$ acting on $a$ or $c$?

Comment: It doesn't matter: $\langle a | B | c \rangle = \langle a | (B | c \rangle) = (B | c \rangle)^\dagger | a \rangle$ as operators in QM are Hermitian. A small notational point --- in general operators are assigned capital letters (and sometimes a carat, e.g. $\hat{B}$).

Comment: Some times it matters. For hermitian operators b you can say it acts on a or c, both of them are well defined. However for anti unitary transformation you cannot apply it to the bra. See Sec 4 J. Sakurai.

Answer (score 0):

This is Dirac notation or bra-ket notation for a matrix element, for some operator $b$. The "ket" $\left|c\right>$ and "bra" $\left<a \right|$ are states which live in a Hilbert space. Kets are like vectors and bras are their dual-vectors which map any state (ket) to the complex numbers via an inner product $\left<a|b\right>$. The first chapter of Modern Quantum Mechanics by Sakurai and the "Formalism" Chapter of Griffith's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics have a more detailed explanation of Hilbert space and Dirac notation if you're interested.

Comment: I’m familiar with bra-ket notation. My question is about the notation with three characters instead of two. What does that mean?

Comment: Where did you see the notation, and what did the text say about it? Did they have an explanation? I suspect they did. Go re-read it, think about it for an hour or so. Then if you don't understand, come back and **edit your question** with a specific point of  confusion.